# How to bind data on a Handlebars.js template for automatic value update?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, template-engine, handlebars.js

There are many [JavaScript MVC frameworks](http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed) right now that work with [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com) offering data binding between the model/controller and the template. Currently I'm implementing Handlebars.js alone (with [jQuery](http://jquery.com)) and needing to bind data between my main code and the template so the latter gets updated automatically. Is there a native way to do it in Handlebars or with a plugin?
If there isn't, is there any component of these MVC frameworks that brings this functionality and can be used stand-alone without the full-stack framework?

Comment: This is on the front page of Handlebars http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: I've read it, can you please point where it says how templates update automatically when values change?

Comment: I am sorry. I thought you're asking how to bind your data to Handlebars' templates. You do need something to add observables to your code such as MVC framework. If you don't want to have the full framework implementation, try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13914/Observer-Design-Pattern-Using-JavaScript, you can create your own with a very tiny code (not as good)

Comment: It seems that adding observable still I have to call the template manually to update the DOM. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @GarciaWebDev Hola Garcia! hey did u find any solution to this problems? cause Im at the same situation. I want to update a handlebar-template (data-grid), adding new items...but it creates problems with my arrays...

Comment: @YoniGeek hola! Well, nothing like a full two-way update these frameworks provide nowadays, but you could declare a setter method on your object and whenever it changes you re-render your object's template. You could take a look at `Object.defineProperty()` for declaring the setter, but it's really IE9+. Otherwhise a simple `MyObject.set(props)` and triggering re-rendering there should work. @MilkyWayJoe mentioned using observables also, didn't used them though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at rivets: https://github.com/mikeric/rivets.  I use backbone, handlebars, and backbone.modelbinding for two-way updates.  Works great.

Backbone.modelbinding (https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding) has been abandoned, but refers to rivets.

Comment: Seems that Rivets.js is what i was looking for, even though i don't need it currently as i'm working with AngularJS which has integrated data binding, it's good to know it exists.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but if i'm correct, handlebars can't be used as template engine for Rivets right? The way I see it, Rivets has it's own template parser.

Comment: Can you explain how to use rivets with handlebars? They don't just work together out the box as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might just want to try using a [Backbone view](http://backbonejs.org/#View) to render your Handlebars template and listen to jQuery events on elements "inside" the view.    You can use Backbone views without having to use the framework's Models, Collections or the Router, but you still have to include the full Backbone library (6.3kb, Packed and gzipped) and Underscore, which might be a problem for you if size is a consideration.